# How do i give OCSP support in my TLS client side code , or is it internally implemented by SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) method?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am confused whether i need to implement the OCSP myself or does openssl implicitly implements it in SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) method. If i need to do it myself then how do i do that ? There is no proper documentation or blog that i could find which clearly states how to do it.

My Code to connect to openssl goes like this:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings(); 
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

BIO * bio;
int x = 0;
long error=0;

SSL_library_init();
SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
SSL * ssl;


if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "CA.CRT", NULL))
{
/* Handle failed load here */
    //Failed
}



bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
error = BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
error = SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

if(bio == NULL){
/* Handle the failure */
    //Failed
}




BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "hostname:443");


if(error = BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0){
/* Handle failed connection */
    //Failed
    return 0;
}



if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
{
    /* Handle the failed verification */
    //Failed
}

char buff[] = "The entire Post request in http format";


if(BIO_write(bio, buff, strlen(buff)) <= 0)
{
if(! BIO_should_retry(bio))
{
    /* Handle failed write here */
    //Failed
}

/* Do something to handle the retry */

}    


USHORT entireResSize = 0;  
BYTE* babuff = NULL;
while(1)
{
    BYTE buffer[10000]={0};
    USHORT currentResSize = 10000;
    currentResSize = BIO_read(bio, buffer, currentResSize);
    if(currentResSize == 0)
    {
    /* Handle closed connection */
        //Failed
        break;
    }
    else if(currentResSize < 0)
    {
    if(! BIO_should_retry(bio))
    {
    /* Handle failed read here */
        //Failed
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        entireResSize += currentResSize;
        babuff = (BYTE*) realloc(babuff,entireResSize);
        strcpy(&babuff[entireResSize - currentResSize], buffer);
    }

    /* Do something to handle the retry */
    }

}


/* To reuse the connection, use this line */

BIO_reset(bio);
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

/* To free it from memory, use this line */

BIO_free_all(bio);
```

Comment: Let me google this for you. Use the following search keys: openssl ocsp C example
...You can find: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ocsp.c or https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj74NPIoMLWAhVFI1AKHc0FDiwQFghAMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fopensource.apple.com%2Fsource%2FOpenSSL%2FOpenSSL-22%2Fopenssl%2Fapps%2Focsp.c&usg=AFQjCNFbgbCYHfiV8mRXCwce2N7shAmOgg

Comment: I specifically mentioned that if there is an implicit implementation of OCSP in the mentioned method . I have already gone through both the links before posting this question . And tried other things too. But the thing is they didn't work for me.